# How to pass masterpage dropdownlist selected value to content page?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a `dropdownlist` control on `masterpage` in asp.net. as follows:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddladults" runat="server" CssClass="input_bg">
      <asp:ListItem Value="0">----Select----</asp:ListItem>
      <asp:ListItem Value="1">1</asp:ListItem>
      <asp:ListItem Value="2">2</asp:ListItem>
      <asp:ListItem Value="3">3</asp:ListItem>
      <asp:ListItem Value="4">4</asp:ListItem>
      <asp:ListItem Value="5">5</asp:ListItem>
      <asp:ListItem Value="6">6</asp:ListItem>
      <asp:ListItem Value="7">7</asp:ListItem>
      <asp:ListItem Value="8">8</asp:ListItem>
      <asp:ListItem Value="9">9</asp:ListItem>
      <asp:ListItem Value="10">10</asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
```

Here I want to pass the selected value to the content page named `Checkavailablity.aspx`.

Please give your ideas.

Answer (score 6):

To get `master page` control values in content page, use `Master.FindControl()`.

Add the following code in the `Content Page`.

### Code

```
DropDownList masterDropDown = (DropDownList)Master.FindControl("ddladults");
String selectedValue=masterDropDown.SelectedItem.Text.ToString();
```

**OR**

```
DropDownList masterDropDown = (DropDownList)Master.FindControl("ddladults");
String selectedValue=masterDropDown.SelectedValue.ToString();
```

Then use that String `selectedValue` for whatever you want to do with.